# Is there any way to get the windows cmd shell to expand wildcard paths?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, wildcards, batch

Occasionally, the cmd shell's inability to expand wildcard paths can really be an inconvenience. I had to pass 100 files in a directory to a program, and couldn't type *.ext. Instead, I used mingw's 'ls' to dump the list to a file, then replaced newlines with spaces, copied and pasted into cmd. Quite a nightmare.

I suspect the answer will be no, but has anyone dealt with this or come up with any way to make this easier?

Comment: Have you considered using something like Powershell instead?

Comment: `I suspect the answer will be no, but has anyone dealt with this or come up with any way to make this easier?`     Actually, I’m having the opposite problem, I am trying to figure out a way to get the command-interpreter to treat its list as strings and *prevent* it from inreptreting them as wildcards. For example, `for %i in (foobar baz really?) do @echo %i` will treat the last item (`really?`) as a filename wildcard, and skip it if there are no files named `really1`, `reallyz`, etc. ☹

Comment: @Synetech - `?` is not a legal character for filenames in the Windows filesystem. The character can only be interpreted as a wildcard. See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN and [Using wildcard characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb490639.aspx) in TechNet.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of files in  some directory separated by spaces?

Answer (score 26):

DOS, and consequently Windows' `cmd.exe`, never supported wildcard expansion by the shell.  It was always up to the application to do the expansion.

This means you will always have to find another route if you're using an application that doesn't support expansion.  You could:

- [Use a FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382957) to run some commands against all the files you're interested in
- Use `dir /b > list.txt` to use the `dir` command to perform the expansion and put the list of files into a text file (you could then use something like an Excel formula if you're really desperate to produce a list of commands to paste into `cmd`, or you could use Excel to transpose the cells so all the filenames are on the same line.)

Comment: He explained that it would be a nightmare to output results of dir into a file and process filtering and copying manually. wmz's answer and of course mine would work without manually filtering a files content.

Comment: @wullxz: It is a nightmare doing it manually.  But if you know some basic Excel, it is surprisingly easy to do something like this very quickly.  The OP's "replacing newlines with spaces" for example is a copy-paste-transpose that takes a couple of seconds.

Comment: right, but it still takes up too much time IMHO.

Comment: @wullxz: Perhaps, but for someone unfamiliar with Powershell wanting to do this as a one-off, it could be considerably faster - and the idea behind this site is to provide useful solutions for people of all skill levels to refer to now and in the future, so really there's no need to tell me off because you think my answer isn't as good as yours.

Comment: *"DOS, and consequently Windows' cmd.exe, never supported wildcard expansion by the shell."* - Not true according to Microsoft. See [Using wildcard characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb490639.aspx) on TechNet. (But I think you are right in practice :o. Otherwise, I would not be here trying to figure out why files are not matched)

Comment: @jww: The link you posted explains the standard use of the wildcard characters, but I can't see any mention of them being expanded by the shell.  Unlike UNIX (and later Linux and Mac), Microsoft left wildcard expansion up to each individual application to implement, passing the command line parameters through as-is.

Comment: DOS command 'dir Filespec /b' works really well, because it creates a list of files, one per line. With the additional '/s' switch, the file names are fully qualified (absolute), and can easily be fed through a for loop to any other command line program that takes a file name. It's the best we can do, since Windows doesn't have a proper globbing feature.

Answer (score 12):

Just use Powershell, which is preinstalled on Windows 7.
Powershell is capable of running cmd commands and does understand wildcards at any place in a path.

To start Powershell just type "powershell" in your start menu search box and hit enter.

---

In case the application expects a string with all filenames in it this is the right script:

```
$delimiter = " "
[string]$files = $nothing ; ls *.txt | % { $files += $_.fullname + $delimiter } ; application.exe $files
```

Change `$delimiter = " "` to `$delimiter = ","` if your application expects a comma separated list of file names.

Explanation of code:

- `[string]$files = $nothing` - creates an empty variable of type `string`
- `;` - is a separator for multiple commands, not a pipeline!
- `ls *.txt | % { $files += $_.fullname + $delimiter }` - gets a list of all text files and creates a string with all filenames separated by the delimiter
- `application.exe $files` - calls the application and passes the file list to it

You can even search for a file pattern recursively by adding `-recurse` to `ls *.txt` so the complete code would look like this:

```
$delimiter = " "
[string]$files = $nothing ; ls *.txt -recurse | % { $files += $_.fullname + $delimiter } ; application.exe $files
```

*Edit:*
To avoid irritations, `ls` and `dir` are aliases of `Get-ChildItem` and `%` is an alias to `ForEach-Object`. I keep my code with aliases used because it's shorter.

**EDIT 2018/04/25:**
Back in 2012 I've been fairly new to PowerShell. Of course there is an easier way though it's not as easy as unix/linux' capability of glob expansion:

`app.exe $(ls *.txt | % {$_.FullName})`

Explanation:

- $() will evaluate the expression inside first and will replace itself
  with the output of that expression (much like backticks do in bash)
- `ls *.txt` gets FileInfo objects of all files that match the glob
  `*.txt`
- because PowerShell is object oriented, we have to output the
  fullname of each FileInfo object. Simply naming an attribute/property
  in PowerShell outputs it by default. `% { $_.FileName }` does that for us. `%` loops over all elements returned by `ls` and outputs each objects FileName.

Comment: Alhough PS is certainly capable to fulfill the reqest and the advice to familiarize with it is sound - it's not as simple as you suggest. Running `start notepad++ *.txt` (with intention to open all textfiles - used notepad++ as it **does** handle multiple names) will get you nowhere

Comment: You could workaround that with `dir *.txt | % { notepad++.exe $_ }`. I tried that with simple notepad, because I don't have notepad++, and it worked. The command receives a list of all txt files in the current directory, passes the list on to the next command which loops through the list and executes notepad++ with the filename as parameter.

Comment: yes, but this is not equivalent. Think about `grep "a b c"` to find *any* of listed strings, where "a b c" would be expanded list

Comment: Sure, it's not equivalent. It'd be bad if powershell would work equivalent to cmd. Powershell is much more flexible than cmd (an evidence is your script and the limitations of it compared to my single-liner). And what's that grep example? grep doesn't exist in powershell nor in cmd. I don't understand your point.

Comment: Running a command **with a list of items as parameter** is not equivalent to running command **multiple times with each element** from a list as a parameter.  Another example: `copy a+b+c result` and `copy a result` `copy b result` `copy c result`. (and grep like utility do exists in PS, it's called `select-string`)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it's easier to loop through all objects of the result than to create a string and append all filenames to it in order to pass that string over to the desired application. I could do that, too, but why should I make things harder when the application behaves the same? (ah, and I know Select-String of course, but it behaves very different than grep)

Comment: there is no reason **if application behaves the same** but how can you know how **an unspecified application** behaves? Read the question carefully, OP only says 'I had to pass 100 files in a directory to *a program*'

Comment: Despite that he didn't name his application, he also didn't mention how his application wants the files to be passed. Anyways, I added the code that would pass all found files as simple string separated by a delimiter to my answer. It is still more handy than cmd code.

Comment: upvoted, btw it's a pity that OP does not care to chime in to explain...

Comment: The code does not work for me. The $files variable is passed to the application.exe as a single positional parameter.

Comment: I get so tired of people saying "just use PowerShell," IMO, PowerShell is mostly good for making simple things complicated.

Comment: And I get tired of people blaming PowerShell. It's preinstalled since Win 7 and almost always does jobs easier than cmd. Just because it's not your basic text based shell we've had for the last decades doesn't mean that its object-oriented approach is always more complicated. It's actually easier to do some operations in powershell than in other shells. Powershell can, for example, parse and manipulate XML files in a object oriented way which makes it the goto shell/language for such things on windows.

Comment: @Åsmund: try my latest edit please. It's simpler and should work.

Answer (score 11):

This will give you a list and also put it in variable named `expanded_list`. Put it in batch file and run with `myBatchFile name myPattern`. Enclose pattern with quotation marks if it includes spaces. Matches files, no dirs. Run without parameters matches all.

```
@echo off
set expanded_list=
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /a:-d "%~1"') do call set expanded_list=%%expanded_list%% "%%F"

echo expanded_list is: 
echo %expanded_list%
```

You can then run you command with `my_command_exec %expanded_list%`

**WARNING!** Maximum size of cmd variable is 8191 characters  (XP onwards), so it's possible to overflow it! You cannot count on the utility to always give you complete list. On the other hand, maximum cmd line length is also 8191 so you would not be able to execute it anyway.

Comment: Note if no arguments are specified then expanded_list will be set to all files in the current directory which may or may not be what is wanted so might want add check for no arguments (e.g. if "%1"=="" ...)

Comment: You don't need `/f` and `dir`, just `for %%f in ("%~1") ...` OTOH `do call` instead of delayedexpansion is a neat trick.

Answer (score 5):

Note, this is in Comment to the posters in a separate thread user619818 and styfle)

DIR can and does allow searching all subdirectories for files matching a specific type.

Note: The Root Directory to check which all subdirectories lie under is assumed to be "C:\My Program\Root" as the author did not give a path name under which these directories are located

```cmd
DIR /B /S "C:\My Program\Root\*.ext"
```

this will give the full file paths and filenames of the source files.

if you only want file names you would have to do as follows

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %A IN ('DIR /B /S "C:\My Program\Root\*.ext"') DO @( Echo.%~nxA )
```

so assuming you want to move all of these files from "C:\My Program\Root\Sub Directories\*.ext" to "D:\Singlefolder\*.ext" you simply do this:

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %A IN ('DIR /B /S "C:\My Program\Root\*.ext"') DO @( MOVE "%~A" "D:\Singlefolder\%~nxA" /Y )
```

Hope that helps others in the future. :)

Comment: You don't need dir; `for /r %f in (\path\*.ext) do @echo %f` (or `%~nf` etc) searches subdirectories, which OP didn't ask for. But it doesn't pass the list as arguments to a program, which OP did want.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The answer given was in response to another answer (as noted at the top) when I was a new member who could not comment, but could leave an answer (kinda backwards of SE IMHO) so was only addressing their comments about `dir` in a `for` loop with a file glob.

Answer (score 3):

This works in cmd.exe

```
dir /b *.ext
```

or

```
echo | dir /b *.ext
```

Comment: This only works for the file name, not any part of the path. For example `dir /b TortoiseSVN\bin\sv*.exe` will show `svn.exe` and `svnadmin.exe`. 
But `dir /b TortoiseSVN\bi*\svn.exe` shows a syntax error.

Comment: check `dir /s /b`. This gives you the full path.

Comment: @WesternGun: but it alo includes subdirectories to any level, which OP didn't ask for.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but with the Linux subsystem for windows, its pretty common to have bash in your PATH now.
If that is the case, then this might do the trick for you:

```
bash -c 'cat *.txt'
```

Comment: note that [single quotes are not special in Windows cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51080215/995714), thus if you run the above command from cmd it won't work. And this also applies to systems with Cygwin or other bash environments

Comment: @phuclv: _CMD_ doesn't treat singlequotes as special, but it also doesn't expand wildcards (the point of this Q), so this passes the command unchanged to WSL (or cygwin etc) which DOES handle singlequotes and it DOES work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `for` loop to pass the list of files to the program:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do start notepad %i
```

Or if you want to pass all files (list) to run **one instance** of the program (eg. pass a list of files separated by spaces):

```
set list=.& (for %i in (*.txt) do set list=!list! %i)& start app.exe !list:~2!
```

In 2nd case, the list variable contains all the files represented by `*.txt`:

```
echo !list:~2!
```

If the program can't detect filenames with spaces, then quote the names:

```
set list=.& (for %i in (*.txt) do set list=!list! "%i")& start app.exe !list:~2!
```

Tested in Win CMD

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple solution to this given by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/expanding-wildcard-arguments?view=msvc-170

Basically, you just link with one of two libraries that will expand wildcards into the argv[] list fed to your program.

To clarify by example, say you have the code:

```cpp
// ExampleFileExpansion.cpp : This outputs the cmd line arguments
//

#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        wcout << i << "\t" << argv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Which normally gives output like:

```
C:\x64\Debug>ExampleFileExpansion *.*

0       ExampleFileExpansion
1       *.*
```

Within Visual Studio, navigate to the project properties page and choose the linker input options | Additional Dependencies. Then, add the library (in this case "wsetargv.obj") and apply the change. Then, Build the project again, from the main menu.

After the change, running the same code gives something like:

```
C:\x64\Debug>ExampleFileExpansion *.*

0       ExampleFileExpansion
1       ExampleF.a660785c.tlog
2       ExampleFileExpansion.exe
3       ExampleFileExpansion.exe.recipe
4       ExampleFileExpansion.ilk
5       ExampleFileExpansion.log
6       ExampleFileExpansion.obj
7       ExampleFileExpansion.pdb
8       ExampleFileExpansion.vcxproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
9       vc143.idb
10      vc143.pdb
```

Here are some screen shots from VS 2022 to illustrate the steps:

[Visual Studio Project Properties Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkBZS.png)

[Choose Linker input options, then Edit to get the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bI2Y.png)

[Enter the appropriate obj file name either wsetargv.obj or setargv.obj depending on whether wmain or main function is declared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq2Wn.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1110645)

Comment: Sure, sorry.  Let me work out an example and I'll post it.  I was looking for the answer to the same question and when I found this, it was so elegant I thought I'd just share what I found.