# Windows batch file, Looping through files in folder to create a parameter list to pass into another script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a Windows batch file that process a bunch of files. As part of this I use the following line:

```
forfiles /p "%~dpn1%LogDir%" /m "%SupportLog%*" /c "cmd /c logreader.py @file > \"%~dpn1%ParsedLogDir%\@file_Logreader.txt\"
```

This works OK, but essentially loops through all my files (%SupportLog%*) and passes each one by one into the "logreader.py" script.

What I really want to do is create a list or parameter of all these files and pass all of them at once into the Python script, such the the command that should be run would resemble:

```
logreader.py "logfile.log" "logfile.log.1" "logfile.log.3" .....
```

I tried to use the SET command within the forfile command such that:

```
forfiles /p "%~dpn1%LogDir%" /m "%SupportLog%*" /c "cmd /c set PARAMS=%PARAMS%@file "
```

However, when run this and leave the ECHO ON, I see:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Path\log" /m "logfile.log*" /c "cmd /c set PARAMS=@file "
```

Which is incorrect. And when I "echo %PARAMS%", I get no result.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Many thank

Comment: have a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths/460648#460648 and this http://superuser.com/questions/759326/obtaining-a-list-of-files-from-a-specific-directory/759607#759607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing environment variables in a *child* `cmd` instance (that's what the `cmd /c` invokes) does not affect environment in the parent `cmd` process. Next code snippet could help:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "LogDir=%~dpn1log"         my guess only
set "SupportLog=logfile.log"   my guess only
set "PARAMS="                  initial value
rem 1st try for /R "%LogDir%" %%a in ("%SupportLog%*") do set PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%~a"
rem 2nd try for %%a in ("%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*") do set "PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%~a""
rem 3rd try
for %%a in ("%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*") do set "PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%~nxa""
echo logreader.py %PARAMS%
```

Note that imperative `logreader.py` is merely `echo`ed for debugging purposes.

However, I don't apprehend target of `>` redirection, sorry...

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~a` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>>`, `2>1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

**Edit**:

- 1st try [`for /R` recurses  the folder tree](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html): rejected; try `for %%a`: [conditionally perform a command on several files](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html);
- 2nd try `"%%~a"` gives fully qualified file name;
- 3rd try `"%%~nxa"` gives bare file name and extension (no path).

Comment: Hi Jose, this is almost perfect, although the the `for /r` seems to recurse the folder tree. Now, this is OK, the first time I run this batch file as I can set the `For` loop early in the batch that evaluates the folder before I create a subfolder to store the parsed file, but if I then run the batch again, if picks up file in the sub folder. (sorry for the multiple comments, I couldn't quite get the hang of these ;()

Comment: Doh. Stupid boy! Just remove the `/r` and set the `SET` to the correct directory. Many thanks, all done, from what I can see. Maybe I should start looking at PowerShell to build such things in the future.

Comment: For reference, the full line that worked was `For %%A in ("%~dpn1%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*") do (
    set PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%A"
)`. This is used in conjunction with passing a file into the batch file in the first place (via a SentTo short cut)