# how to expand filenames on command line

Tags: windows, command-line, wildcards

I'm using a batch file to execute an `awk` program and feed it filenames.

Question:
How do I get it to expand the filenames on the command line?

Syntax:

`Command.exe *.rpt > out.txt`

Exact:

`"C:\Users\user\Utilities\mawk.exe" -f "C:\Users\user\My Projects\AWK\EmailSQLResults.awk" C:\Temp\SQL\*.rpt > "C:\Temp\SQL\EmailResults.txt"`

Result:

`mawk: cannot open C:\Temp\SQL\*.rpt (Invalid argument)`

Windows 10.
Standard CMD window.
mawk 1.3.4 20140914

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[Is there any way to get the windows cmd shell to expand wildcard paths?](https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths?rq=1)

I looked before I posted, but apparently not hard enough.   8: -(